# Is it possible/feasible to build a large-scale Flex application for free?

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex

I want to create a fairly large-scale Flex web application that has a similar interface style to Grooveshark.

When it comes to web development, I have always used the common PHP/HTML/JavaScript technologies. Now, I want to try something new and develop a RIA using Flex.

Using PHP/HTML/JavaScript, I am able to develop my entire website with free tools. Now, I'm wondering if I am able to do the same thing with a Flex web application?

Is it possible/feasible to develop a Flex web application for free? If not, what would be the lowest cost I would need to spend? And, whatever the option, what are the tools that would be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Do I need Flex Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466111/do-i-need-flex-builder)
- [What is the best Flex IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311887/what-is-the-best-most-productive-flex-ide)
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=free+flex
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flex+flashdevelop (if on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Have you been to Adobe's Flex website?  You can do anything you need to with the free Flex SDK, available here http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex4sdk.

To develop without Flex Builder will be more tedious and require a more in-depth understanding of how to position and organize graphic elements.  I hope you have lots of time :)

Comment: To get you kick started on that though, you could download the FB4 trial and get stuck in, figure it out and then drop it after the trial expires